# Python: is using decorator to change method arguments a bad thing?

Tags: python

I implemented a decorator to change a class method's arguments in this way:

```
def some_decorator(class_method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kargs):
        if self._current_view = self.WEAPON:
            items = self._weapons
        elif self._current_view = self.OTHER:
            items = self._others
        for item_id, item in items.iteritems():
            class_method(self, item, *args, **kargs)
        items_to_remove = []
        for item_id, each_item in items.iteritems:
            if each_item.out_dated():
                item_to_remove.append(item_id)
        for item_id in items_to_remove:
            del items[item_id]
    return wrapper

class SomeClass(object):
    @some_decorator
    def update_status(self, item, status):
        item.update_status(status)

    @some_decorator
    def refresh(self, item):
        item.refresh()
```

The main purpose of the `some_decorator` is automatically call method on every item of `SomeClass` then do some cleaning. Since there may be many methods I need to call on the items, I don't want to repeatedly write the for loop and the `clean_items` code.

Without the decorator, the `SomeClass` will be like:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def update_status(self, status):
        if self._current_view = self.WEAPON:
            items = self._weapons
        elif self._current_view = self.OTHER:
            items = self._others
        for item_id, item in items.iteritems():
            item.update_status(status)
        items_to_remove = []
        for item_id, each_item in items.iteritems:
            if each_item.out_dated():
                item_to_remove.append(item_id)
        for item_id in items_to_remove:
            del items[item_id]

    @some_decorator
    def refresh(self):
        if self._current_view = self.WEAPON:
            items = self._weapons
        elif self._current_view = self.OTHER:
            items = self._others
        for item_id, item in items.iteritems():
            item.refresh()
        items_to_remove = []
        for item_id, each_item in items.iteritems:
            if each_item.out_dated():
                item_to_remove.append(item_id)
        for item_id in items_to_remove:
            del items[item_id]
```

When I actually the methods, I will do:

```
a = SomeClass()
a.update_status(1)
a.refresh()
```

Here is the problem, the parameters I pass to `update_status` is different from the arguments of the declaration of `update_status`, the `item` is missed since is automatically passed by the `some_decorator`. I wonder if it's a bad thing since it may cause confusion when other programmers see it.

If it's indeed a very bad pattern, are there any other pattern can do the same thing for me without causing confusion?

Comment: Okay, based on the new edited version of the question, I'm inclined to agree with this kind of decorator. Still think some refactoring might be required. I would say a container class / mixin for `_item_list` may be more useful than just using a list. Then have that class accept a function which it then executes just like your decorator. Yes, it's additional code and has the same functionality as the decorator, but is cleaner and more maintainable in the future. Just my 2 cents. +1 on a good question. Hope it's not closed as too broad. (Btw, the edit has some typos/syntax errors.)

Comment: Where does the variable `status` come from in the longer version of `refresh`? This still looks like it would be easy to factor out the common parts to a third helper function, then each of `update_status` and `refresh` would simply call that helper function, possibly with different args to get slightly different behavior. The decorator approach still seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @aneroid thank you, can you post an example container as a answer?

Comment: Yup, working on it ;-) Trying to decide between sub-classing `list` or [UserList](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html#module-UserList).

Comment: @Mr.F sorry the `update_status` in the end is a typo, I've removed it. The main reason I use the decorator is that in all the common parts, I need to call a method of each `item` and the method may have different arguments, like the `update_status` and the `refresh`. And I want to avoid something like `getattr(item, method_name)(*args, **kargs)`.

Comment: See my edit for a way to abstract this that I think is much more straightforward than the decorator.

Comment: Great answer from @Mr.F so my mixin isn't required :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think even a boring module-level function would be a strong choice here. It doesn't seem that these operations that happen *to* your class instances really has any good reason to "belong" to the class as a class method at all.

```
def update_status(some_item_haver, new_status):
    for item in some_item_haver.items:
        item.update_status(new_status)
```

Now, it could be used with many different classes, even ones whose methods would be an ill-advised pain to modify with a decorator, like a third party class from a library someone else wrote.

```
a = SomeClass()
b = SomeChildOfA()
c = SomeThirdPartyThingAlsoWithItems()

update_status(a, "beep")
update_status(b, "bop")
update_status(c, "Vote for Bernie Sanders!")
```

**Edit after the update**

```
class SomeClass(object):
    # __init__ and other stuff
    #...

    def helper(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._current_view == self.WEAPON:
            items = self._weapons
        elif self._current_view == self.OTHER:
            items = self._others


        # The abstract part
        for item_id, item in items.iteritems():
            getattr(item, func)(*args, **kwargs)


        items_to_remove = []
        for item_id, each_item in items.iteritems:
            if each_item.out_dated():
                item_to_remove.append(item_id)
        for item_id in items_to_remove:
            del items[item_id]


    def update_status(self, status):
        self.helper('update_status', status)

    def refresh(self):
        self.helper('refresh')
```

Comment: Thank you. This is close to what I first wrote. Then I use the decorator to avoid the `getattr(item, func)(*args, **kargs)`. But it seems the decorator will cause more confusion so maybe I will get back to `getattr` function call.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was going to put after the OP edit, but didn't think to make a simplified helper like this. Nice! Was planning a `list`-based mixin to manage items rather than just in the class and ran into issues for `self`, so was passing the instance of `SomeClass` to it separately and not in `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I think in this case, more explicit is better.  Why not leave the decorators off and just use for-loops in the method itself:

```
def update_status(self, status):
    for item in self.items:
        item.update_status(status)

def refresh(self):
    for item in self.items:
        item.refresh()
```

Comment: The reason I use the decorator is that for different method like `update_status` and `refresh` there are so many lines of code like the for loop that I don't want to hand write repeatedly(it's tiresome and error-prone.

Comment: @kkpattern In that case, write another helper function that just does the looping part, then the bodies of `update_status` would call the looping function with some extra args. Also, why would a lot of lines be repeated? Repeating the single line of the for statement should be no problem, and if the logic in the loops is necessary and different for each different function, it's not repetitive. If you could update the example in the question, we might be able to help factor out whatever the repeated parts are.